# javascript: what does /*@ @*/ mean?

Tags: javascript, comments

Can someone explain how the beginning and end of the html5shim script works?

the script starts with  `/*@` and ends with `@*/`like this:

```
/*@cc_on(function(a,b){function ........ (this,document);@*/
```

What is the `/*@ @*/` doing?

I would expect the /* */ sequence to comment out all lines in between them, but since the script executes, that cant be the case here? I'm confused.

found at:

> http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IE's JScript supports ‘conditional compilation’, a trick of hiding special browser-specific information in comments. The idea is that `/*@...@*/` is such an unusual sequence of characters that it is safe to repurpose it to introduce this new syntax-level feature.

html5shiv uses it to create a piece of code that won't even try to run on most browsers (which, like you did, will interpret the whole thing as a commend), but which has special meaning to IE.

[MS doc here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahx1z4fs%28VS.80%29.aspx). No other JS engine supports this. Typically you might favour more explicit behaviour-sniffing code instead, but if you really need to detect an IE feature that doesn't expose itself to sniffing otherwise, it can be handy.

Comment: "No other JS engine supports this"...isn't that the point? ;)

Comment: @Artfunkel: well, other browsers have picked up other browser extensions so it's not outside the realms of possibility that someone else might implement some of the features of CC. Probably not a good idea now everyone uses it exclusively to detect IE, though...

Answer (score 7):

It's an IE-ism for "conditional compilation": http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml

Comment: But his example does not use any meta conditionals in that script, so _why_ would this be in use here?

Comment: because using @cc guarantees it'll be executed only on IE.